# Format date to "YYYY-MM-DD" before post data to an API , Redux-Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I use Formik module for handling form and DateInput of "react-hichestan-datetimepicker" module in my project.
Output of DateInput is "2019-10-25T20:30:00.000Z". I want to send **date value** as this format **"2019-10-25"** to API.
I change the format in onSubmit attribute of Formik.

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    date: ""
  }}
  onSubmit={(values, action) => {
    const data = { 
      ...values, 
      date: values.date.split("T")[0]
    };
    dispatch(
      createWorkingShift({ data, history: props.history })
    );
  }}
//...
```

here is saga:

```
const { data, history } = action.payload;
  try {
    const createWorkingShift = yield call(async () => {
      const workingShift = await httpService.post(
        "http://api.../v1/manager/ws/create",
        data
      );
      if (workingShift.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error("failed");
      }
      return {
        data: workingShift.data.working_shift,
        message: "success"
      };
    }); 
    yield put({ type: CREATE_WORKING_SHIFT_SUCCESS, payload: createWorkingShift });
    //...
```

with action:

```
export const createWorkingShift = payload => {
  return {
    type: CREATE_WORKING_SHIFT_REQUESTED,
    payload
  };
};
```

Date format change correctly in data variable in onSubmit, **but data not sent to API**.

When i delete `date: values.date.split("T")[0]` data delivery is successful!

I don't know what and where is the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it works before but not after, are you sure the api accepts a date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD"? It could require the full timestamp and is rejecting the date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".

Comment: @azundo It accepts this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com)

```
const formatedDateString = moment(yourdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();
```